# Troubleshooting URL iFrame Component

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components

I am sending a Url to a component that leverages iFrame functionality. I have verified that the Url string is being passed and cannot understand why it is simply displaying a blank screen. When I follow the Url that is generated, I get the content I am looking for. Does anyone see any issue with the component build?

Component:

```
<aura:component controller="CH_Account_Summary_Report_Controller" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId">
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id" />
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
    <aura:attribute name="Url" type="String"/>
    <iframe source="{!v.Url}" width="100%"/>
</aura:component>
```

Apex Controller (verified the data is getting passed back):

```
    public with sharing class CH_Account_Summary_Report_Controller {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static string getReportURL(Id AccountId)
    {
        system.debug(AccountId);
        Account act = [SELECT SEG_SCH_ID__c FROM Account WHERE Id=:AccountId];
        string UCN = act.SEG_SCH_ID__c;
        string Url = 'https://dev-jasper.scholastic.com/jasperserver/flow.html?_flowId=viewReportFlow&reportUnit=%2FUAT%2FCRM_Reports%2FRevenue_Summary_Report&ReportFlag=RU&UCN='+UCN+'&ParentFolderUri=%2FUAT%2FCRM_Reports&reportLocale=en_US&j_username=SFDC_user&j_password=%24prinG%23123&standAlone=true&decorate=no';

        return Url;
    }
}
```

Component Controller:

```
    ({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        var action = component.get("c.getReportURL");
        action.setParams({
            "AccountId": component.get("v.recordId")
        });
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            if(response.getState() == "SUCCESS"){
                component.set("v.Url", response.getReturnValue());
                //alert(response.getReturnValue());
            }
            else if (response.getState() == "ERROR"){
                $A.log("ERRORS", response.getError());
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }

})
```

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: Does your browser's console show any errors or warnings when you're trying to iframe this content? Such as: `Refused to display 'https://.....' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.`

Comment: No there are no warnings that are similar in nature.

Comment: I think there's a password in the url. If it's not an important password that's fine, of course. If it is important than you might want to change it.